# Why are moderators here blocking clear answers to questions?

Tags: biophysics

I presented a very insightful answer to a question about breaking molecular bonds via electromagnetism. I put a great deal of time and effort into including diagrams and a 3-d perspective of the molecules the question asker was clearly talking about. A moderator "rob" waltzed in and deleted it saying that he felt it was a "springboard" onto another topic.

The truth is that there is only one reason for breaking molecular bonds using electromagnetism, that is circumventing the mitochondria mechanism in the human body to produce a biological energy source by breaking ionic bonds.

In short, i am very dissapointed by this site and the hypercritical moderation.

Comment: there is a stackexchange site called physics meta which you will find subheaded under this physics site. It is there where questions like yours are usually posted. Suggest you migrate it there and look for responses.

Comment: [Migrated](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10718/44126).

Comment: I'm locking this since any further activity should happen on the meta version of this question (see rob's link).